# How to send the response for user at first, and then still running?

Tags: php, yii2

The `php-resque` is a good idea of dealing with the above situation.

But now I don't want to use this method, I want to use the `php` functions that don't rely on any third tools to send the http response from user at first , and then still running to finish other work.

By the way,if this method exists,how it about running in `Yii2` environment?

Comment: `php-resque` doesn't "continue" running after it have sent a response to the user. It is a library for setting up background jobs and queues, using redis, which isn't really the same thing. PHP is built to get a request, handle it from top to bottom. Any output is sent to the browser and when that's done, the script is done.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your comment.I konw that the `php-resque` is combining reids to deal with the jobs of queues.I will still finding my ideal way.